# Macro produces negative font.colorindex values

Tags: excel, vba

Clues to possible reason at the end of this initial discussion.....

A simple VBA macro code line like:

```
FontCol = Cells(K, AmntCol).Font.ColorIndex
```

reports, with the cursor hovering over "FontCol", the value "1"
- which is the index value for black.

yet when this value is "published" to the relevant (active) Excel spreadsheet with:

```
Cells(RowRef, ColRef) = FontCol
```

the **Cell addressed as above shows -5 instead of 1** (as one example of the problem)

"1" is what you expect to see for black, and I cannot even work out what "-5" relates to
let alone why it is also not what seems to be in play in the VBA code.
- and if I write "-5" into some code logic, no useful result would come from it, which confirms that the real underlying value is 1 and not -5.

It seems that no amount of formatting of the (landing) cell or changing the "Dimension as statement" for FontCol, to "integer" or "string" or "variant" changes what is published to the cell.

I've not been able to source any information on this issue. The closest was something about long numbers wrapping around shorter numbers in the index space and a residual driving things...whatever that is supposed to mean.

I really would to resolve this as I was intending to use ColorIndex values as a way of editing cell values safely.

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Additional to above - in response.

Changing Dim of variable/s from "integer" to "long" makes no difference.

In preparing to provide sample code as below I have determined part of the problem - its seems its speed related. But first the code.

''''
    Sub FontMacroIssue()

```
Dim I As Long
Dim FontCol As Long

For I = 36 To 51
    FontCol = Cells(I, 10).Font.ColorIndex
    If FontCol = 3 Then
        Cells(I, 18) = "Red"
        Cells(I, 19) = FontCol
    Else
        Cells(I, 18) = "Not Red"
        Cells(I, 19) = FontCol
    End If
Next I

End Sub
''''
```

The above is being run on a Windows 10 64 bit machine (that dual boots into Linux)...this should not be relevant.

If the above is run as is then the output is mostly/all "not red" and the string of FontCol values print out as,

1 -5 -5 -5 -5 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -5 -7 - and if it is slowed, as
1  3  3  3  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  1

By slowed, I mean running the macro in debug mode with a break point at "Next I" or in a similar place, and then keying the F5 button (say) twice a second. The output for the full speed case is mostly/all "not red" but is the correct reporting of "red" and "not red" when slowed for the font being assessed.

So my question/s now are more, "is this behaviour normal", "how can I best slow things down to get a correct result" OR "what code is more effective" ?
edit...

I am inclined to agree with Fun Thomas as even 2 cycles/sec brings up the problem.
I do not have an answer but some comments that might help.
1.  My hard drive is a 2 TB SSD
2.  The spreadsheet concerned has over 46000 lines.
3.  It surely is more than coincidence that:
    8 -7 = 1  with both 1 and -7 being reported for black font, and
    8 -5 = 3  with both 3 and -5 being reported for red font.
Thanks

Comment: What is the **Dim** statement for `FontCol`?

Comment: Try, please `Dim FontCol As Long`...

Comment: You probably get a result of -4105, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolorindex where is says that -4105 is 'automatic color', and -4142 is 'no color'.

Comment: You should post the whole code. Everything seems to be fine on my end. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62102615/edit) your code. You are obviously not telling us enough. if the code is in a procedure with arguments, a missing `ByVal` could be the issue. BTW Is the cell formatting `General`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use a simple three lines code and see if the problem appears, also: `Dim FontCol As Long` `FontCol = ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex` and `Debug.Print FontCol`. What can you see in Imediate Window? If you see the correct value, the problem must be found in your whole code...

Comment: Are you sure you want to deal with ActiveSheet? Else you should qualify `Cells` (you should qualify if anyhow...)

Comment: Btw: This is for sure not related to execution speed.

Comment: Thanks Guys, but nothing to add really beyond my last edit - that reported -5 and 3 being reported for Red and 1 and -7 for black. Its all absolutely repeatable and unavoidable in the what seems like standard situation I have. In fact, for the moment I've just written a macro that assumes that either 3 or -5 will be returned for red font and all is well ? !!!. I did try the cell.select,  and then active.cell. font.colorindex idea that was suggested by a poster, but still got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The [Font.ColorIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.colorindex) returns:

The color is specified as an index value into the current color palette, or as one of the following [XlColorIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolorindex) constants: xlColorIndexAutomatic or xlColorIndexNone.

The constants will show as integer values -4105 en -4142 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Event Procedure Issue

You might have an event procedure that is messing with your results.

[Workbook Download (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SO864wAJ3BAkSVHVz1bOuHkS9ShwOzFK/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

- The following event procedure sort of replicates your issue. The first code goes into a standard module (`Module1`) and the second goes into the sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`).
- You only run the first code and it will return the right values in ranges `R36:R51` and `T36:T51` and it will 'randomly' return the right or wrong values in range `S36:S51`.
- Additionally when you input values manually in the range `S36:S51`
  and if they are numbers, after confirming by e.g. pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the
  entered values will 'randomly' either be decreased by `8` or not.

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FontMacroIssue()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim FontCol As Long

    For i = 36 To 51
        FontCol = Cells(i, 10).Font.ColorIndex
        If FontCol = 3 Then
            Cells(i, 18).Value = "Red"
        Else
            Cells(i, 18).Value = "Not Red"
        End If
        Cells(i, 19).Value = FontCol
        Cells(i, 20).Value = FontCol
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TargetCol As Long = 19
    Const TargetRows As String = "36:51"
    Const Offset As Long = 8

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Columns(TargetCol))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = Intersect(rng, Rows(TargetRows))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng
        If Round(Rnd()) = 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            cel.Value = cel.Value - Offset
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next cel

    Exit Sub

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```